# Updating model data: in the sever or in the client first?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am using Angularjs for my client side and Web API for the server side. 
I interested of what being the correct way to update the data of my application? Assuming I want to update an Employee's name/age/whatever should I change it's fields locally with angularjs then send a request to the server in order to save those changes OR should I first send a request to the server in order to 'try' saving those changes and only if the saving operation has been successfully done, localy merge the client's model with the updated data? 
Thanks.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: angular1/angular2 uses two way data binding.you dont need to update it locally.You can send it on remote API for processing

Comment: OK but what if the remote API has failed updating it for some reason (DB Server is down / server side validation failed / etc..) It will result in having wrong data in the client side as the update has happened there already by the 2 way data binding..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most clear way to do that - is to update send request for updating to server, and from server response which will include updated data.

Reasons to do such way:

1. Your data flow is always will be consistent
2. In case request failed, you can notify user: Something went wrong, wanna try again? (You can find such behavior in every day usage of big applications).
3. For now you just want to update data with a simple value. Maybe later you will change your mind, and will need to process it before assign to angular model, in such case there will be no need to process on both sides (client/server), you can process it on server and get response with result.